# How to upload form data along with image in spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring

I am working on a usecase to upload student details along with his image in spring boot. The entity class looks like
below.

```
public class Student{
   private int rollNo;
   private String name;
   // few more fields
   
   @Lob 
   private byte[] picture;

  // getters setters
 
} 


JSP file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Student Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="rollNo"/>
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <!-- some more fields -->
  <input type="file" name="picture"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Registration">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

1. How should i handle the form data in my controller method? In a nutshell how to write controller method to handle both form data and image?

Answer (score 0):

```
the very basic idea could be as follows 

@RestController
public class ImageUploadController {

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam(required=true, value="picture") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(name = "rollNo") String rollNo, @RequestParam(name = "name") String name) {

  }
}
```

Comment: what if the entity class contains more number of fields which may  not be in this case. Do we need to specify @RequestParam(name = "XYZ")  for all the fields? or is there any other shorter way? i mean can we bind them as an object?